# increment a variable value inside a while loop in a shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop, increment

I'm trying to increment a variable value in a while loop, but I want to increment it twice. By "twice" I mean increment variable value first time, then do some operation and then increment already incremented value once more, and this is all inside a while loop. My code looks like this:

```
    i=1
    setglobal="SET GLOBAL "
    while [ $i -le $# ]
    do
         assign=$setglobal$i=$($i+1)
         START=`date +%s`
         mysql $database -u $user -se "$assign;select
         here goes my database query, not important"
         END=`date +%s`
         echo $END - $START | bc>>output.txt
         i=$(($i+1))
         mysqld restart
    done
```

And I have a list of arguments sent to my shell: innodb_change_buffer_max_size 16 key_buffer_size 1431655770, as 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th arguments respectively. So I want the while loop to do:

```
    SET GLOBAL innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 16
```

after

```
    assign=$setglobal$i=$($i+1)
```

and

```
    SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 1431655770
```

after

```
    i=$(($i+1))
    assign=$setglobal$i=$($i+1)
```

As a result, in my output.txt I should have got the running time of each query, however I get only four zeros. So I guess my loop is either not doing this part "SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 512" correctly, or it is not doing the right incrementation. Could anyone tell me what might be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

[glenn jackman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22179173/45375) offers `bash` solutions.

However, given that you've generically tagged your question `shell` and that your code seems to use only POSIX-compliant features (except for errors), I assume that you're looking for a **POSIX-compliant solution**:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure that parameters were passed and that they were passed in pairs.
if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ $(( $# % 2 )) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: Please pass parameters in pairs, and pass at least one pair." >&2
  exit 2
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do # Continue while arguments remain.

  # Store the (next) pair of parameters in variables.
  name=$1
  val=$2
  shift 2 # Remove the (next) 2 positional parameters from the start of the array.

  # Synthesize the mysql SET statement.
  assign="SET GLOBAL $name=$val"

  # Get start timestanp (resolution in seconds).
  start=$(date +%s)

  # Invoke the mysql command.
  mysql $database -u $user -se "$assign;select
  here goes my database query, not important"

  # Get end timestamp.
  end=$(date +%s)

  # Calculate the execution time span and append it to the output file.
  echo $(( end - start )) >>output.txt

  # Restart mysql.
  mysqld restart

done
```

---

As for **what you've tried**:

- `$($i+1)` cannot work as a reference to the `$i`-th  positional parameter:

  - Since `$(...)` is a *command substitution* (the modern equivalent of `` `...` ``), the expanded result of `$i+1` would actually be interpreted as a *command* to execute, which is not the intent.
- Using POSIX features only, there is no direct way of referencing a positional parameter by *index*.

  - By contrast, in `bash` you could use `${@:i:1}`, but that's a nonstandard extension).
- Therefore, the simplest approach is to use `shift` to *consume* positional parameters (remove them from the start of the array of parameters) after saving their values in variables, and then checking whether any are left with `[ $# -gt 0 ]`. This also obviates the need for auxiliary index variable `$i`.
- While `echo $END - $START | bc` works, there's no need to involve external utility `bc`, because simple arithmetic expansion `$(( END - START ))` will do.
- It's best to avoid variable names such as `$START` and `$END`, because all-uppercase shell-variable names can [conflict with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that mysql can read commands from stdin, more readable than a
single double quoted string.

```
while (( $# > 1 )); do
    var=$1
    val=$2
    shift 2
    start=$SECONDS

    mysql $database -u $user -s <<ENDSQL
SET GLOBAL $var=$val;
select ...
ENDSQL

    echo $(( $SECONDS - $start )) >> output.txt
    mysqld restart
done
```

If you have bash 4, I'd process the arguments like this:

```
declare -A vars
while (( $# > 1 )); do
    vars[$1]=$2
    shift 2
done

foreach var "${!vars[@]}"; do
    start=$SECONDS

    mysql $database -u $user -s <<ENDSQL
SET GLOBAL $var=${vars[$var]};
# ... rest is the same
done
```

Assuming you can set multiple sql global in one session:

```
sql_commands=()
while (( $# > 1 )); do
    sql_commands+=( "SET GLOBAL $1=$2;" )
    shift 2
done
sql_commands+=( "select ... from ... where ...;" )

start=$SECONDS

printf "%s\n" "${sql_commands[@]}" |  mysql $database -u $user -s

echo $(( $SECONDS - $start )) >> output.txt
mysqld restart
```